# Arithmetic overflow error with genealogytree

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tcolorbox, genealogytree

Using the wonderful package `genealogytree`, I made a tree. The problem is that it is becoming so large that I get the error:

> ! Arithmetic overflow.
>   I can't evaluate this expression, since the result is out of range.

I am not quite sure if this is related to `pgfplots` (see 2.6.2 in [`pgfplots` documentation](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf)) or `tikz` (it does not seem that `genealogytree` relies on `pgfplots`).

Anyway, below I propose a MWE to reproduce the error. Instead of including hundreds of nodes, I use an very large value for `node size`. The question is, is it possible to get rid of this error (without reducing `node size` of course, that is already small in the complete tree)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[processing=database,node size=70cm]
  child{
    g[male]{name=Jim,birth={1-1-1}{Everywhere}}
    p[female]{name=Jane}
    child{
      g[male]{name=Alfred}
      c[male]{name=Joe}
      c[female]{name=Heather}
      c[female]{name=Barbara}
    }
    child{
      g[female]{name=Berta}
      c[male]{name=Howard}
    }
    c[male]{name=Charles}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `[node size=60cm,processing=tcbox]`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It works for that simplistic example, but unfortunately not if I add a field, such as `name` or `birth` (which is  essential  for large trees). I'll edit the MWE .

Comment: Which expression is 'this expression'?

Comment: @cfr For the above example, `! Arithmetic overflow.
<to be read again>
}
l.22 \end{genealogypicture}
I can't evaluate this expression,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer of the package author, Thomas F. Strum, from [github](https://github.com/T-F-S/genealogytree/issues/15):

> [...] take a look at the reduced templates introduced with version
>   v1.21 (2017/09/15), e.g. `template=database pole reduced` (see Page
>   256ff of the documentation). You could use such a template or look at
>   its source code to get ideas on how to brew your own style.

This solved my issue.